# What is the easiest way I can power multiple dc motors at the same time?

Tags: power-supply

(inexperienced) I found some 250-500w dc motors that I plan to control with some digital PWM controllers. Only problem I'm running into is that all the dc power supplies I find upon searching are hundreds of dollars, and extremely big and bulky.

I don't have this kind of money. Isn't there some way I can power these motors with a normal DC power supply within the rating limit, such as the ones used to power laptops? Surely there are cheap hobbyist DC power supplies rated for under 1000w? You know, ones that don't weigh 40 lbs?

Comment: As you go up in power regardless of application the cost always gets higher. Especially when dealing with motors, as things just need to be bigger to handle the current. A fixed output solution might be cheaper, but it's still going to cost a bit. If you want lower cost you'll need to look at getting something used.

What voltage and current are you looking at using? For a given power rating you can find less expensive units if they have higher voltage and lower current ratings.

Look at digikey for some examples on cost.

Comment: Not enough information. What do you want to drive? Starting a fan is much different to starting a conveyor, for example. Provide part numbers, voltage, amps, etc., and links to the manufacturers' data sheets. Please **add the information to your question** and not in the comments.

Comment: I am looking to have 3 different motors all running at different speeds, yet, variable when I need it. The digital PWM I have found accomplishes controlling the speed easily. I just need a reliable way to power each motor. If my Laptop can run on 1000w of DC power with a little power brick, then why can this not be retrofitted in some way to power a motor? The main reason I am not looking to use AC motors is because I need consistent speed/torque that I can control somewhat precisely.

Comment: Dude - If you have a 1 kW laptop....words fail me.

Comment: When deciding on what kind of electric motor to use for a project, there are several things to consider:  1. rotational speed  2. power  3. startup torque  4. variability of speed  5. robustness.
Unless you give us any kind of hint as to what your project requires, it will be hard to offer any help.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious place to start is eBay. You don't say what voltage you need, but let's say you want 24 volts. Search on "24 VDC power supply" and look at what's available. I gave it a try and found several in the 20A (480 watts) range for about $50.

And no, 1kW is not ordinarily hobbyist level.

Comment: Ah, in my mind I always thought of hobbyist level as anything running off standard wall power. Under 1.5kw. When you get above that range you start needing special power panels and such as found in industrial settings. Would it be possible for me to use something such as a computer power supply? Cost isn't so much the issue as is the factor of not wanting to deal with heavy bulky power units.

Comment: Well if your motors are rated for 5V or 12V then a computer PSU with the appropriate current rating can easily be adapted to drive them. But you haven't even hinted at the motor's voltage or current ratings, so ...

Comment: I don't have the motors yet, I just found a bunch of different ones online. I won't be ordering anything until I know I have everything planned out with respect to running them. So as of now the voltage is not set in stone. I want to plan everything out before I go buying things.

Comment: 1 kW is more than 1 horsepower. Now, it's true that there are hobbies which suck up that much energy, but they are not widespread. It's the sort of power level that will chew off fingers if you stick them in the wrong place (small table saw, for instance), so building stuff that uses that much power is definitely a minority taste.

Comment: A desktop ATX supply that's higher end (Corsair, etc.) has some pretty beefy 12V rails designed to feed high-end GPUs with fairly tight regulation. You could look at those to run your motors if 12V is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to power a motor with a PWM controller but without a bulky input power supply for the PWM controller is to buy or build a PWM controller that connects directly to a standard wall outlet.